# Unable to compile basic tikz codes from pgfmanual

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error

In last semester, I started using LaTeX just for assignments and homework but now I wanted to take to the next level.

I started with the `tikz` library following the pgfmanual. Everytime I try to compile my code I get different result from the documentation, or it won't even compile.

For example this first code I copied it right from the documentation

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=3] 

    \clip (-2, -0.2) rectangle (2,0.8);
    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
    \draw[<->](-1.5, 0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[<->](0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5);
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];

    \draw[very thick,red]
        (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
    \draw[very thick blue]
        (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);

    \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black] (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm)
        arc [start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=3mm] --cycle;
    \foreach \x\xtext in {-1,-0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
        \draw (\x cm, 1pt) -- (\x cm, -1pt) node [anchor=north] {$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1,-0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
        \draw (1pt, \y cm) -- (-1pt, \y cm) node [anchor=east] {$\ytext$};


    \path [name path=upward line] (1,0) -- (1,1);
    \path [name path=sloped line] (0,0) -- (30:1.5cm);
    \draw [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=t}]
            [very thick, orange]  (1,0) -- node [right=1pt,fill=white];
            {$\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black} =
                \frac{{\color{red}\sin \alpha}}{\color{blue} \cos \alpha}$} (t);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is the result when I compile it:

[image: Result after I compile that code]

This is the result shown in the documentation[image]:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
I have installed Texlive iso on it.

Comment: On which page did you take that code from? The first code in the Ti*k*Z - PGF manual is on the title page, and clearly it is not this. The second code is on page 29, and it is not that long.

Comment: The code specified in the MWE is not correct.

Comment: This is not exactly the first though, this is on page 44. And some of the codes won't even compile and would end up in errors. like the one 118 in Part III.

Comment: @NaumanAfsar Most code in the Ti*k*Z manual is not for copy-paste. You have to include additional libraries. Read the entire section to have a good preamble. In your code, I see that at least you don't have `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`, etc.

Comment: Except that [>=stealth] I didn't touch anything else.

Comment: I know it's not for copy paste, but as I was getting different results so I got annoyed and and copied the whole thing ;). I will check it that library again and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @NaumanAfsar On page 118 there are no code. There are two codes on page 44. So what do you mean? I can't get it.

Comment: I don't know what manual are you following but I opened mine with the command `texdoc tikz`

Comment: Why do you have the same profile picture as [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)?

Comment: @NaumanAfsar Consider updating your distribution then. I am following [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: lol I don't know who that is, but I guess I took it from twitter. I saw it on my TL one day and I liked it.

Comment: @NaumanAfsar Suggestion: Please include the source of your profile picture to your profile description.

Comment: @NaumanAfsar Also, please include where you have your profile description from. It is not yours, I'm sure.

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @JouleV I know it's not mine, as I said I took it from my twitter timeline. Do you really want me to go through my 31K likes on twitter to find out who tweeted that? If it's that big a deal then say so.

Comment: @NaumanAfsar Well, it doesn't worth then. However, I asked the author of your profile picture and (s)he said that you don't have the permission to have that profile picture, so I think you should make one yourself and for you only. Using others' without credit is not a serious problem in many countries, but it is in some countries (at least not in my country, but I don't like it). Or you can ask someone to make it (see [CarLaTeX's profile picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex)).

Comment: I'll change mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just copy and paste code examples from the manual.  You actually have to read the manual to find out how to use the examples.  In this case you are missing `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`.

Here is the relevant part from the tutorial:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \clip (-2,-0.2) rectangle (2,0.8);
  \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
  \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm)
    arc [start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=3mm] -- cycle;
  \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
  \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) coordinate (y axis);
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];

  \draw[very thick,red]
    (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
  \draw[very thick,blue]
    (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
  \path [name path=upward line] (1,0) -- (1,1);
  \path [name path=sloped line] (0,0) -- (30:1.5cm);
  \draw [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=t}]
    [very thick,orange] (1,0) -- node [right=1pt,fill=white]
    {$\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black}=
      \frac{{\color{red}\sin \alpha}}{\color{blue}\cos \alpha}$} (t);

  \draw (0,0) -- (t);

  \foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
  \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the first two sentences!

Comment: I am sorry I just realized I wasn't very clear in my question. I was following the manual bit by bit but as I started getting different results... I got soo annoyed that I just took the whole thing and pasted it.